# Can I validate one field in two different groups?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsley.js

I have a form that contains these elements:

- `email`
- `code`  and a btn "SendCode"
- `pwd` and a btn "SendPwd"

User may click any of the two buttons and I would then like to check that the input-field associated with that button as well as `email` validate.

I guess I could put each of them into their own group and then validate the appropriate group + `email`, but I was wondering if there's a way to avoid defining 3 groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed the sentence

> Can be multiple. eg: `data-parsley-group='["foo", "bar"]`

in [the doc](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#usage-field) (which I had missed or misunderstood before). So it's doable with `data-parsley-group='["code", "pwd"]` for the `email`-field in my example.